# Store calculated value in database in this scenario?

Tags: database, database-design, database-theory

I store readings in a database from sensors for a Temperature monitoring system.

There's 2 types of reading: air and product. The product temperature is represents the slow temperature change of an item of food versus the actual air temperature.

They 2 temperatures are taken from different sensors (different locations within the environment, usually a large controlled environment) so they are not related (i.e. I cannot derive the product temperature from the air temperature).

Initially the product temperature I was provided with was already damped by the sensor, however whoever wrote the firmware made a mistake so the damped value is incorrect, and now I instead have to take the un-damped reading from the product sensor and apply the damping myself based on the last few readings in the database.

When a new reading comes in, I look at the last few undamped readings, and the last damped reading, and determine a new damped reading from that.

My question is: Should I store this calculated reading as well as the undamped reading, or should I calculate it in a view leaving all physically stored readings undamped?

One thing that might influence this: The readings are critical; alarms rows are generated against the readings when they go out of tolerance: it is to prevent food poisoning and people can lose there jobs over it. People sign off the values they see, so those values must never change..

Normally I would use a view and put the calculation in the view, but I'm a little nervous about doing that this time. If the calculation gets "tweaked" I then have to make the view more complicated to use the old calculation before a certain timestamp, etc. (which is fine; I just have to be careful wherever I query the reading values - I don't like nesting views in other views as sometimes it can slow the query..).

What would you do in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Examples will be useful

Answer (score 0):

The underlying idea from the relational model is "logical data independence". Among other things, SQL views implement logical data independence.

So you can *start* by putting the calculation in a view. Later, when it becomes too complex to maintain that way, you can move the calculation to a SQL function or SQL stored procedure, or you can move the calculation to application code. You can store the results in a base table if you want to. Then update the view definition.

The view's clients should continue to work as if nothing had changed.

Here's one problem with storing *this* calculated value in a base table: you *probably* can't write a CHECK constraint to guarantee it was calculated correctly. This is a problem regardless of whether you display the value in a view. That means you might need some kind of administrative procedure to periodically validate the data.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I agree re logical data independence; I tend to look at the database independently and always keep the business/data logic within the database itself using views and stored procedures.  It is then easy for any client to interact with it.  So, either way the view presented to the client would have been the same.  I just was in two minds whether to store the derived value or not given how critical it is.  From what you've said, calculating it in the view or a sproc seems to be favourable.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit .. The CHECK isn't a problem.  Every update to the database must be done via a stored procedure which can do more complicated checks if necessary.  I think it was Thomas Kyte (Oracle) that coined the phrase "Transactional API" for this kind of system.  The stored procedure in question for submitting a reading has to do a fair amount of work anyway (such as generate an alarm if necessary).  It all works very nicely - however I wanted a sanity check on my thinking for this particular problem.